# I want to create autokey phrases that are invoked immediately from the phrase using engine.create_phrase

Tags: autokey

I'm modifying the included sample script `Abbreviation from selection.py` from Autokey, to make it create phrases that are invoked immediately. `However the engine.create_phrase()` method doesn't let you modify the properties of an abbreviation, such as the `backspace`, `ignoreCase` properties etc. it just lets you set the abbreviation text.

`engine.create_phrase` does return the created phrase, and I'm hoping there's a way of modifying it, but I don't know the structure of the returned object. I tried calling `myCreatedPhrase.get_description()` using a method I found in the [source code](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/master/lib/autokey/model/phrase.py#L252), but it doesn't seem to work, and there's no way of debugging autokey scripts(?).